# jquery - how to resize two textareas when I manually resize one

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

I have a textarea and a div side by side. Both controls are manually resizeable by draging the resize icon in the bottom right hand corner of each.

How do I resize **both** the textarea and the div when I resize either one of them. I would like to keep both the textarea and the div the same size.

I have searced SO & Google, but was unable to locate anything reated to the issue I have.

Here is a visual representation of what I have:

[image]

Comment: Can you post some code

Comment: Did not write it but with a quick google I discovered this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gbouthenot/D2bZd/). It appears to do what you are asking...